# Definir una única variable del tipo "conn" o una para cada uso dentro del programa?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Cuando trabajamos con una base de datos y en una parte del código abrimos una conexión para crear una tabla y en otra parte del código abrimos una conexión para guardar datos...

se acostumbra usar una misma variable de conexión o es mejor crear una variable para cada uso como forma de evitar errores?

Pregunto porque en un código en el cual estoy trabajando tuve que crear dos variables diferentes ya que si guardaba datos dos veces me daba un error, incluso si las conexiones eran cerradas correctamente al terminar cada proceso

Al final tuve que solucionar con algo del estilo

```
Dim connMakeDB As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("MiBaseDatos.sqlite")
Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MiBaseDatos.sqlite;Version=3")


'Ejemplo de uso de conn para crear una tabla

    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Autos (marca VARCHAR(20), modelo VARCHAR(20), color VARCHAR(20))"

    'Abro conexión
    conn.Open()

    'Defino comando SQLite para establecer la conexión
    Dim cmdConexion As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

    Try
        cmdConexion.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

    'Cierro la conexión
conn.Close()
```

y en otro procedimiento usar

```
'Ejemplo de uso de conn para guardar datos
Dim connGrabar = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MiBaseDatos.sqlite;Version=3")
    Try
        Using (connGrabar)
            connGrabar.Open()

            sql = "INSERT INTO autos (marca, modelo, color) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)"
            Dim cmdGuardar As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, connGrabar)
            cmdGuardar.CommandText = sql
            cmdGuardar.Connection = connGrabar
            cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", cboMarca.Text)
            cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboModelo.Text)
            cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", cboColor.Text)
            cmdGuardar.ExecuteNonQuery()

            connGrabar.Close()
        End Using
```

De lo contrario a pesar de que las conexiones se cerraban al terminar cada procedimiento me daba un error del tipo

**System.ObjectDisposedException: No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado.
Nombre del objeto: 'SQLiteConnection'.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define la conexion dentro de un bloque `Using` de esta forma sera el connection pool de ado.net quien se encargara de administrar el objeto de conexion, es mas veras que no es necesario definir el `Close()` de la conexion, porque al salir del using el objeto queda invalidado y es administrado por ado.net

[Agrupación de conexiones en SQL Server (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)

La estructura del codigo deberia ser

```
Dim connstring As String = "Data Source=MiBaseDatos.sqlite;Version=3"

Using (connGrabar As New SQLiteConnection(connstring))
    connGrabar.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO autos (marca, modelo, color) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)"
    Dim cmdGuardar As New SQLiteCommand(sql, connGrabar)
    cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", cboMarca.Text)
    cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboModelo.Text)
    cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", cboColor.Text)
    cmdGuardar.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

Defines en todas las partes del codigo la instancia de conexion dentro del `Using`

```
Dim connstring As String = "Data Source=MiBaseDatos.sqlite;Version=3"

Using (conn As New SQLiteConnection(connstring))
    Try
        conn.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Autos (marca VARCHAR(20), modelo VARCHAR(20), color VARCHAR(20))"
        Dim cmdConexion As New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)
        cmdConexion.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Using
```

---

Si bien el link aplica a Sql Server quizas sea bueno analizar como se comporta con Sqlite

[SQLite/C# Connection Pooling and Prepared Statement Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703814/sqlite-c-connection-pooling-and-prepared-statement-confusion)

Comment: Comprendido. Muy interesante que no sea necesario cerrarlas conexiones.